# Create data.table with column names as variable

Tags: r, data.table, calculated-columns

I have this awkward problem and I would like to understand why it doesn't work.

```
test <- rbind(test, data.table(evalq(names(test)[1]) = rep("", 5), 
                               evalq(names(test)[2]) = rep("", 5)))
```

The problem is comming from this :

```
data.table(evalq(names(test)[1]) = rep("", 5), 
                                   evalq(names(test)[2]) = rep("", 5)))
```

I tried to repalce `evalq(names(test)[1])` by `eval(names(test)[1])` or by `names(test)[1]` but nothing resolves this problem.

And curiously this version works without problem :

```
data.table("var1" = rep("", 5), "var2" = rep("", 5)))
```

Thank for you help :)

Comment: use `setnames` instead

Comment: What is the awkward part here? Are you seeing a different behavior with `data.frame`?

Comment: The problem is that I can create a data.table like this : data.table("myVar" = ..) but in the case when I have myVar storing a a character, how can you do something like that :data.table(myVar = ...) ?

Comment: You can't. And it's not data.table specific. You can try your own `data.table` function though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of `names(test)[1]` is wrong because you are pointing to the column name and you are not extracting the column name to be used as variable. From `?evalq`:

> The `evalq` form is equivalent to `eval`(quote(expr), ...). eval evaluates its first argument in the current scope before passing it to the evaluator: `evalq` avoids this.

After that,

> `eval` evaluates the expr argument in the environment specified by `envir` and returns the computed value.

You can't use it as a variable name for a list. I suppose it works only at the environment level.

If you want to use as a varibale name an info coming from colnames you can do this:

```
assign(names(test)[1], rep("", 5))
```

But it will not work in your case because it is always related to the enviroment.

Executing this:

```
test <- rbind(test, data.table(assign(names(test)[1], rep("", 5)), 
                               assign(names(test)[2], rep("", 5))))
```

You will have an error but you will also have 2 variables in the global environment called `names(test)[1]` and `names(test)[2]` containing "" 5 times.

If you don't what to set manually colnames, you can do this:

A test dataframe

```
  test<-data.frame(Date=c("Jan-2002","Feb-2002","Mar-2002","Apr-2002","May-2002","Jun-2002"),
                        "Value"=c(3.1,2.86,3.37,3.8,3.78,3.61))
```

Binding using `rbindlist` from package `data.table`

```
test <- rbindlist(list(test, data.frame(cbind(rep("", 5),rep("", 5)))),use.names = F)
```

The Output

```
test
        Date Value
 1: Jan-2002   3.1
 2: Feb-2002  2.86
 3: Mar-2002  3.37
 4: Apr-2002   3.8
 5: May-2002  3.78
 6: Jun-2002  3.61
 7:               
 8:               
 9:               
10:               
11:
```

Comment: I fail to understand how is it related to the question.

Comment: Yes, I used use.names = F to avoid the problem, but do you have an answer about why my code fails to create a data table ?

Comment: Added a little explanation, I don't know if this will be exhaustive

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I understand now that data.table evaluates variable in the scope of the object. But, why eval(.., envir = .GlobalEnv) still don't work ?

Comment: You are pointing to the Global Environment, this is the base of your general problem.